# Jaspersoft Expression Editor

Tags: jasper-reports

I am needing to count the number of rows in a table that are equal to "X" . What expression do I use to do that? How do I count each row and not count the rows that do not meet the requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Achieve this You need to create Two Variable.

Variable_1 will have the expression as follows

```
    <variable name="Variable_1" class="java.lang.Integer">
         <variableExpression><![CDATA[IF(EQUALS($F{Field_Name},"X"),1,0)]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
```

Variable 2 will sum Variable 1

```
    <variable name="Variable_2" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
         <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{Variable_1}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
```

you Need not use Variable 1 in your Report, But Place Variable 2 in Summary Band.